# when i save any pdf and tiff image the other users from sharing can't see it!

Tags: pdf, tiff

we have 3 pcs and there is 3 folder i shared it with them, when i put excel and word or any other thing in the folder they can see it and change it and do anything they want but now since 1 month
when i scan any paper with pdf or tiff format the users from others computers they don't have permissions to access the file
also when i save any pdf or tiff format from my email and put it in the sharing folder they also can't to access

i don't what happen but i didn't change any setting in my pc

note: i use windows xp computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are on Windows XP.
The software which creates the file might not give permissions to everyone (maybe only the creator/proprietary)

- Go to your folder
- Right click on the file
- Click on the `security` tab

From now, I can' t guarantee you will have exactly the same configuration (furthermore my system is in french so the translation might not be exact). We will try to give access to everyone, so :

- Click on `everyone` if it exists
- Tick the little box in the `authorize` column, in front of `read`
- Repeat this for every permission you want to give to the user (you can click everything if you're sure the file is not a classified secret ;))
- Click Ok

**If `everyone` does not exist**, you will have to create it, clicking on `add`. Then enter the translation of `everyone` in your language (for example, in french `Tout le monde`), and click on `verify`. Then give the authorizations like previously explained.

Comment: thanks alot but i don't have security tab, in the other pc i use win7 and there is security tab, but here i use xp windows so there isn't and when i create a word file the other can do anything with it so im not sure if the problem is with security

Comment: (Assuming your drive is formatted with NTFS) you can switch on the Security tab from Folder Options. In any Explorer window: Tools > Folder Options > View (tab) > Advanced settings > Un-tick 'Use simple file sharing'